# d3.js graph has incorrect visualisation of path in firefox

Tags: svg, d3.js, path

I'll try to be as clear as possibile (i'm not very good in english). I have a d3 static force graph and I need it to be cross browser. I already had a big problem with Internet Explorer, because it doesn't support SVG correctly. And i solved it by drawing elliptic arc without markers as suggested in another topic.

Now i have the following problem:

In every browser tested (Chrome, IE, Opera and Safari so far) my graph is shown correctly, in other words links length starts and stop exactly in the x,y coordinate of source and target node), while in firefox, using same data, every link go beyond the node x,y coordinate.

With Chrome i get  [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U2rp.png)

With Firefox i get  [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0iUa.png)

The code i'm using is the same for both browser, if you need it i can try to make a JSfiddle working.

Comment: We will need the source. Please make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Sorry for that, i knew it was necessary, but i thought that maybe someone has already encountered a similar issue. Now the problem for me is that i made a complex structure for my graph and the entire code is about 1000 lines. I'll try in the next few days to create a simplified version of it in jsfiddle (hopefully by creating it I'll find a solution).